# Diagnostics & Performance hub is crashing on certain projects (0x80070057)

Tags: performance, windows-runtime, diagnostics

I have 2 WinStore applications under development. They are both real time applications so performance is of importance. I'm planning to make use of the built in performance & diagnostics tools that comes with visual studio 2013 (and later versions). The first application works fine but for the second application visual studio is immediately crashing and it's impossible to make captures.

This happens immediately after I press the *Start diagnostic...* button on the debug menu. It only occur for WinStore configs and only for the particular startup project. If I change startup project it doesn't occur but then I can't run the app ofc so it doesn't help me. This indicate that there's some setup in the startup that's incompatible with the diagnostics hub I think?

The end of the visual studio log contains an error message (related to WebDiagnosticsAttach):

```
...
  <entry>
    <record>583</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:15.750</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{22512D50-40BC-4DEA-89B1-21D70BB4218E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>584</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:15.750</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [DiagnosticsHubPackage]</description>
    <guid>{22512D50-40BC-4DEA-89B1-21D70BB4218E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>585</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.109</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [DiagnosticsHubPackage]</description>
    <guid>{22512D50-40BC-4DEA-89B1-21D70BB4218E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>586</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.171</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{B66F381B-48DE-4C10-B71B-EF9A2A808D85}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>587</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.171</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.Package.HtmlToolHostPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{B66F381B-48DE-4C10-B71B-EF9A2A808D85}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>588</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.187</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{8C0C630B-37F1-11E3-8259-6C3BE516EAD0}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>589</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.187</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [WebDiagnosticsAttach Package]</description>
    <guid>{8C0C630B-37F1-11E3-8259-6C3BE516EAD0}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>590</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.187</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{8C0C630B-37F1-11E3-8259-6C3BE516EAD0}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>591</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.187</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [WebDiagnosticsAttach Package]</description>
    <guid>{8C0C630B-37F1-11E3-8259-6C3BE516EAD0}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>592</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.203</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.Package.HtmlToolHostPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]</description>
    <guid>{B66F381B-48DE-4C10-B71B-EF9A2A808D85}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>593</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.218</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{BEB01DDF-9D2B-435B-A9E7-76557E2B6B52}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>594</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.218</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [VsDebugPresentationPackage,version=14.0.0.0,publicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,culture=neutral]</description>
    <guid>{BEB01DDF-9D2B-435B-A9E7-76557E2B6B52}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>595</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.234</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [VsDebugPresentationPackage,version=14.0.0.0,publicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,culture=neutral]</description>
    <guid>{BEB01DDF-9D2B-435B-A9E7-76557E2B6B52}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>596</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.249</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{F419E6BB-F72F-42CF-ACFE-D0D0E17FCB17}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>597</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.249</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsHubServicePackage]</description>
    <guid>{F419E6BB-F72F-42CF-ACFE-D0D0E17FCB17}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>598</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.437</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{494B203E-3C94-40AB-B331-6CB32460B617}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>599</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.437</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage]</description>
    <guid>{494B203E-3C94-40AB-B331-6CB32460B617}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>600</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.562</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage]</description>
    <guid>{494B203E-3C94-40AB-B331-6CB32460B617}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>601</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.562</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{F20B4E46-CBC8-4AE7-B10A-43D1D73B4145}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>602</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.562</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [VsPixPackage]</description>
    <guid>{F20B4E46-CBC8-4AE7-B10A-43D1D73B4145}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>603</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:16.562</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [VsPixPackage]</description>
    <guid>{F20B4E46-CBC8-4AE7-B10A-43D1D73B4145}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>604</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:36.511</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{65D2E08F-C7DD-4512-9486-156881C91F6E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>605</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:36.511</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TailoredProjectServices]</description>
    <guid>{65D2E08F-C7DD-4512-9486-156881C91F6E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>606</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:18:36.515</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TailoredProjectServices]</description>
    <guid>{65D2E08F-C7DD-4512-9486-156881C91F6E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>607</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:19:52.097</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{BB4BF712-FCF7-4D17-83BB-93E6478B4E5D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>608</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:19:52.097</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [User Feed]</description>
    <guid>{BB4BF712-FCF7-4D17-83BB-93E6478B4E5D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>609</record>
    <time>2015/01/12 15:19:52.098</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [User Feed]</description>
    <guid>{BB4BF712-FCF7-4D17-83BB-93E6478B4E5D}</guid>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

I'm not sure if this indicate what the problem could be or if it's unrelated?

When attached to visual studio I get following error message:

> First-chance exception at 0x76EC2F71 (KernelBase.dll) in devenv.exe:
>   0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80070057, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
>   0x00000000, 0x74310000). Unhandled exception at 0x76EC2F71
>   (KernelBase.dll) in devenv.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80070057,
>   0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x74310000).

If anybody has an idea of what this might be, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: As this looks like a bug, I think this is better answered via a support message to microsoft.